# WPF App.config System.TypeInitializationException

Tags: c#, wpf, app-config

In my WPF program, I need to read / save a setting "totalhours" from the App.config file. I've used this file once before in another project, but when I used it this time, it keeps giving me System.TypeInitializationException error and going into break mode (visual studio). Heres the App.config code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
  </startup>
  <appSetings>
    <add key="TotalHours" value="0"/>
  </appSetings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: You should paste the code that throws. Also, there must be an InnerException wrapped inside your exception. Check its value in the VS exception window (when it throws).

Comment: Show how you try to achieve it.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are missing **t** in **appSetings** .It should be spelled as **appSettings** not **appSetings**.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
  <configuration>
   <configSections>
   </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="TotalHours" value="0"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```